# Scraping images: having lists of thumbnails/images instead of strings

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I would like to know if it would be possible to scrape images rather than string format as a list of Thumbnails in a dataframe. 
I have a dataframe with two columns, one for the links and one for the images. It is currently showing images as strings. However, since I would need to analyse the images for classification, I would probably prefer to have thumbnails.

Do you know if it is something that would be possible to have/do?

The code for scraping images is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


list_websites=["http://news.m.istella.it/cluster?originalClust…","https://www.optimagazine.com/2020/03/25/"," https://www.playhitmusic.it/2020/03/","https://www.zazoom.it/2020-03-26/","https://oggiscienza.it/2015/11/17/"]

list_images=[]

for link in list_websites:

    res=requests.get(link)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    images =bs.find_all('img')

    list_images.append((link, [image['src'] for image in images]))

df = pd.DataFrame(list_images, columns = ['Link', 'Images'])
```

Comment: So there are several scenarios I can imagine here, can you tell me which one is correct? 1. You want to fetch thumbnails instead of image urls when web-scraping
2. You want to see actual thumbnails in the dataframe instead of url links?

Comment: I would like to see the thumbnails instead of image urls when I scrape the images from those websites. The code above (that I would like to keep, but just edit a bit to let me scrape thumbnails) is collecting urls rather than images. Since I would need to classify images, I think it would be better to have already images rather that strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited) Here's a piece of code that does this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError
import base64
import io 

list_websites=["https://www.optimagazine.com/2020/03/25/","https://www.zazoom.it/2020-03-26/","https://oggiscienza.it/2015/11/17/"]

list_images=[]

for link in list_websites:

    res=requests.get(link)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    images = bs.find_all('img')

    list_images.extend([(link, image['src']) for image in images ])


df = pd.DataFrame(list_images, columns = ['Link', 'Images'])
df.Images = df.Images.str.lower()
df = df[df.Images.str.endswith("jpg") | df.Images.str.endswith("jpeg") | df.Images.str.endswith("png")]

def get_thumbnail(path):
    response = requests.get(path)
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))    
    img.thumbnail((150, 150), Image.LANCZOS)
    return img

def image_base64(url):
    if url.endswith(".png"):
        image_type = "png"
    else:
        image_type = "jpeg"
    im = get_thumbnail(url)
    with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
        im.save(buffer, image_type)
        return base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

def image_formatter(im):
    try:
        return f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{image_base64(im)}">'
    except UnidentifiedImageError as e: 
        return "NA"

df["thumbnail"] = df.Images.apply(image_formatter)
HTML(df[['Link', 'Images']].to_html(formatters={'Images': image_formatter}, escape=False))
```

I believe the result is what you're looking for (looks pretty cool):

This is based on some code from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/stassl/displaying-inline-images-in-pandas-dataframe

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Roy2012. Is there any way to include this in my code above? I would prefer to use that code, just editing a bit to collect images rather than strings/urls. I think the answer would be in using to_html, but I do not know how to include this part. Maybe I am saying something wrong...

Comment: @LucaDiMauro - downloading from URL per your request. Note that I made a small change to your original code, so it would put every image URL in a different pandas row.

Comment: Thank you @Roy2012. I got the following error running your code: `ImportError: cannot import name 'UnidentifiedImageError' from 'PIL' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)`
It seems because of `from PIL import Image, UnidentifiedImageError`. Do you know how get it working?

Comment: Emm. If the type of the exception isn’t critical, just catch any exception.

Comment: More specifically, just replace "except UnidentifiedImageError as e:" with "except :"

Comment: Thank you @Roy2012